# What does `"{:0>2d}".format(count)` mean in the following code?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I come across this code...

```
def coordinate(my_list):
    coordinate = []     
    count = -1
    for num in my_list:
         count += 1
         coordinate.append("%s-%s" % ("{:0>2d}".format(count), my_list[count]))
    return coordinate       

print ( coordinate(['x','y','z']))
```

the expected output type is

```
coordinate(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
>>>['00-A', '01-B', '02-C', '03-D']
```

Now my question is I am not understanding

```
coordinate.append("%s-%s" % ("{:0>2d}".format(count), my_list[count]))
```

this part of code... What exactly `"{:0>2d}"` and `.format(count)` is used for? How they work? Please explain.

Comment: One is a string. The other is a method that operates on the string. Both are documented in the documentation.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 6):

It's [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) function.

In the format string `"{:0>2d}"`:

`d` means expecting an int:

```
>>> "{:d}".format(3)
'3'
```

`2d` means formats to 2 characters using padding (whitespace by default)

```
>>> "{:2d}".format(3)
' 3'
```

`0>` means using `0` as padding, and right adjust the result:

```
>>> "{:0>2d}".format(3)
'03'
```

Comment: The `>` is *redundant* here, because `02d` would already right-align. It'd be different if a larger field width was picked, though, because `02d` is effectively the same as `0=2d`, meaning that the `0` padding is placed between the sign and the value, while `0>2d` places the padding *before* the sign. But with a field width of 2 even a single-digit negative value already takes 2 characters. Try `-42` and `0>5d`, then compare that with `05d` or `0=5d`..